# SQL For Standardizing Postal Codes

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that has a PostalCode column.  The data in here is not standardized - Sometimes the postal code appears is H0H 0H0 and othertimes it is H0H0H0.  Using SQL only, how can I ensure each of these postal codes is standardized as H0H 0H0 ?

Comment: Which SQL flavour? MySQL? SQLServer? Oracle? SQLite? etc?

Comment: @MPelletier, SQL Server.

Comment: Do you want the standard format persisted in the database (so the values in the columns will be of the format XXX XXX), or just *presented* that way when you query those values?

Comment: @MPelletier, it's the first part of the first sentence of the question. Now it also has an `sql-server` tag, which wasn't there before.

Comment: @rdineiu: Oh, big ol' DUH for me! Thanks! I focused more on the rest of the question. Plus the postal code example is the special one reserved for Santa Claus, guess that must have gotten me excited.

Comment: @MPelletier, hehe, didn't know about Santa's postal code. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, it really depends on how it's entered into the database (i.e. you should be controlling how this is entered and managed pre-insertion). But for updating your table, you could do this to put them in the right format, with the space in between:

```
Update MyTable Set PostalCode=SubStr(LTrim(PostalCode),0,3) || ' ' || SubStr(RTrim(PostalCode),-3,3);
```

This might vary depending on the actual database engine. At the time of writing, OP had not specified which.

Comment: The data didn't come from an input form on our end, so we weren't able to control the format, unfortunately.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you can be sure that those are the only two formats:

```
select left(replace(post_code,' ',''),3) + right(replace(post_code,' ',''),3)
```

If the case can vary wrap the result in UPPER()